# Series solution to a heat-style equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, sturm-liouville

The function $u(x,t)$ is defined in $0<x<1$ and obeys the pde:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} - u$$

Alongside BCs:

$$u_x = 0\ when\ x =0$$

and

$$u_x = -1\ when\ x =1$$

Alongside an IC

$$u(x,0) = u_0(x)$$

I need to find a series solution that obeys sturm liouville properties as well as derive an orthogonality condition. My general solution was calculated as:

$$u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n \exp(-n^2\pi^2 t)\sin(n\pi 
 x) $$

Which I'm fairly certain is wrong. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: The boundary condition at $x = 1$ isn't homogeneous. If you let $u(x,t) = v(x,t) - x^{2}/2$ then your problem above turns into an inhomogeneous PDE in $v$ with homogeneous boundary conditions and a slightly modified initial condition, which is amenable to separation of variables.

Comment: What would the solution be

Comment: I haven't tried it so I don't know, though your spatial eigenfunctions would be cosines not sines.

Answer (score 1):

Your equations are
$$
            u_t = u_{xx}-u \\
            u_x(0,t)=0,\;\; u_{x}(1,t)=-1,\\ u(x,0)=u_0(x).
$$
The condition $u_x(1,t)=-1$ is inhomogeneous, which poses a problem for separation of variables. The functions $e^{x}, e^{-x}$ are solutions of $u_{xx}-u=0$. So the function
$$-\cosh(x)/\sinh(1)$$
is a solution of
$$
u_{xx}-u=0, u_{x}(0)=0, u_{x}(1)=-1.
$$
Therefore $v=u+\cosh(x)/\sinh(1)$ is a solution of
$$
              v_t = v_{xx}-v \\
              v_{x}(0,t)=0,\;\; v_{x}(1,t)=0 \\              v(x,0)=u(x,0)+\cosh(x)/\sinh(1)=u_0(x)+\cosh(x)/\sinh(1).
$$
This is solvable with separation of variables.